# Internet Explorer 7 "content advisor" shut off

Tags: internet-explorer, blocking, internet-explorer-7, web-filtering

I'm using Internet Explorer 7.

I turned off Content-Adviser.  (Its constant pop-ups make the entire idea useless.)

I deleted all my "approved" sites.
I deleted all my "blocked" sites.
I turned off all my "rating" blocks.

I've turned EVERYTHING off.

But it *STILL* asks for my password.

Why?  (And how do I delete my password?)

Comment: Any reason you are still using insecure IE7?...http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/worldwide-sites.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of info on [this page](http://www.pchell.com/support/contentadvisor.shtml):

> #### How to Remove Content Advisor Password in Internet Explorer
>
> The following steps will remove any password set in the Internet Explorer Content Advisor
>   and allow you to reset the program to its original state.
>
> 1) Click on Start and choose Run.
>
> 2) Type in `RegEdit` and select OK.
>
> 3) Now click on the little plus sign<sup>1</sup> to the left of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
>
> 4) Continue to drill down, always clicking on the plus sign at the left of the named key,
>   through Software, Microsoft, Windows, CurrentVersion and Policies.
>
> 5) Now click on the Ratings folder.
>
> 6) In the right pane of the RegEdit window, you'll see an icon called Key. Click on it
>   and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.
>
> 7)  Exit RegEdit (e.g., by clicking on the <kbd>X</kbd> button).
>   You've just deleted your original Content Advisor password.
>
> 8) Restart the computer and run Internet Explorer again.
>
> 9) Choose View and then Internet Options (or Options for version 3.x).
>   For IE 5 or greater, click on Tools, Internet Options.
>
> 10) Click on the Content tab and click on Disable.
>   When asked for a password, don't enter anything; just click on OK.
>   This will disable Content Advisor because there's no longer a password.

<sup>1</sup> There may be some other symbol there; e.g., a triangle.